# How to increment 4 bit counter by 1 bit when a button is pressed

Tags: verilog, counter

I am writing a stop watch program on the Nexys4 FPGA. I can start, stop, and reset the stopwatch, but I'm having trouble implementing an increment feature. The increment feature is a button, that when pressed, will increment the clock by 1 millisecond. So if the seven segment display is showing 1:002 and the increment button is pressed, the display will show 1:003. Here is a snippet of my code for the counter:

```
always @ (posedge (clk), posedge(rst))
begin 


if (rst == 1'b1)begin
        Dig0 <= 4'b0000;
        Dig1 <= 4'b0000;
        Dig2 <= 4'b0000;
        Dig3 <= 4'b0000;
    end 

//increment if inc
else if(state == 2'b11)// && Dig3 < 4'b1001)begin
begin
    Dig0 <= Dig0 + 4'b0001;
    state <= 2'b00;
end


//only continue if Cen is 01 & not inc
else if(Cen == 2'b01)begin  

    //add 1 to first digit up till 9
    Dig0 <= Dig0 + 1'b1;

    //reset if == 10    
        if(Dig0 > 4'b1001)begin
            Dig0 <= 4'b0000;

            //add 1 to second digit (when first resets) up till 9
            Dig1 <= Dig1 + 1'b1;
            end
            //reset if == 10
            if(Dig1 == 4'b1010)begin
                Dig1 <= 4'b0000;

                //add 1 to third digit (when second reset) up till 9
                Dig2 <= Dig2 + 1'b1;
                end
                //reset if == 10
                if(Dig2 == 4'b1010)begin
                    Dig2 <= 4'b0000;

                    //add 1 to fourth digit (when third reset) up till 9
                    Dig3 <= Dig3 + 1'b1;
                    end
                    //reset if == 10
                    if(Dig3 > 4'b1001)begin
                        Dig3 <= 4'b0000;

                    end         
    end
```

Cen is coming from a state machine where state 2'b11 is increment, 2'b01 is count, and 2'b00 is stop. I can't figure out how to get it to increment just one bit. Whenever I hit increment is just counts forever. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Would it not be easier to have 1 counter and decode that into digits for the display? Also sorting out your code indentation will make it much easier to read and spot bugs.

Comment: As Morgan said, fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Without the state-machine code only I can only make a guess about the problem . You need to post the state-machine code too to conform the guess.

But the most probable reason for the counter continuing to increment is that Cen is also high (2'b01) while state is 2'b11.

```
Cycle 1 ) - state == 2'b11 , Cen == 2'b01 
            Dig0 +1 , state = 0 

Cycle 2 )  - state = 0 , Cen == 2'b01 
              goes to else clause and the counter continues to increment 
              as long as Cen is 2'b01
```

There are also few issue you may need to fix .

1) in the increment section (state = 2'b11 ) you still need to  check and increment all the 4 digits ( Dig0-3 ) as incrementing Dig0 ( more that 9 times ) will result in roll over to the next digit and so on.

2) Its better to update the state machine variables  in a single always block. so its better to move the statement `state = 2'b0` into the  state-machine.

3) Also as already suggested in the comments you could have a single counter and decode it for digits.